# provisionCOmposer.js returns error message of "bad host name"

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I am following the standard bot framework composer deployment script, as following:

```
cmd_prompts> node provisionComposer.js 
  --tenantId=<my tenantid> 
  --subscriptionId=<my subscriptionid>...
```

It was working pretty well at the beginning. Then it failed after I deleted several existing resources from my subscription. The following is a copy of the error returned by the provisionComposer.js script:

```
{
   "Code": "BadRequest",
   "Message": "The host name nyname01-xyz_env.azurewebsites.net is invalid.",
   "Target": null,
   "Details": [
          {
           "Message": "The host name nyname01-xyz_env.azurewebsites.net is invalid."
          },
    {
       "Code": "BadRequest"
     },
   {
      "ErrorEntity": {
       "ExtendedCode": "04003",
       "MessageTemplate": "The host name {0} is invalid.",
       "Parameters": [
       "nyname01-xyz_env.azurewebsites.net"
       ],
        "Code": "BadRequest",
        "Message": "The host name nyname01-xyz_env.azurewebsites.net is invalid."
      }
    }
   ],
   "Innererror": null
 }
```

Result:

> Provision failed

Can anyone shed some light?  Appreciate your help.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, it used to work and then you “deleted several existing resources” and now it doesn’t work any more?

Comment: It turns out the prvisionComposer.js is programmed to use the input parameter to generate the API endpoint, and is embedded with an undocumented feature to enforce a hostname naming schema. For example, it wouldn't allow you to include an underline to specify the hostname, and it will throw out an exception error code to abort the deployment. It's a mystery to me that why Microsoft never document such hidden input requirements, The same script (provision composer.js) is loaded with similar undocumented input restriction.

Comment: In addition to the host naming schema restriction (no underline), one may also want to add a new input parameter: tenatId (which can be found by viewing your azure active directory). It's really a mystery to me why Microsoft never correct this kind of ambiguity in their documentation.

Comment: Fair point around undocumented constraints. I believe there might be some changes coming in this area, but feel free to make a request for the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot) or a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Type%3A+Enhancement%2C+Needs-triage&template=bot-framework-composer-feature-request.md&title=) in the repo.

Comment: @Dana: Thanks for the suggestion. :-)